# Add multiple columns and header names in for loop VBA

Tags: excel, vba

how is it possible to insert variable columns in active sheet with column names too?
The below code add the column name at first and last column only.

```
Sub AddColumns()
    Dim i As Long
    
    'loop to insert new column(s)
    For i = 1 To 4
        Columns(2).EntireColumn.Insert
        ' Add column names
        Cells(1, i) = "Level" & " " & i
    Next i
End Sub
```

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your code is that you always insert a new column **after** the second column. Whereas you start writing the header in column 1.

Try this code

```vb
Sub AddColumns()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    
    Const colInsertBeforeAs Long = 2
    Const cntInsertColumns As Long = 4
    
    'moves colInsertBefore cntInsertColumns to the right
    ws.Columns(colInsertBefore).Resize(, cntInsertColumns).Insert
    
    ' Add column names
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To cntInsertColumns
        ws.Cells(1, colInsertBeforeAs - 1  + i) = "Level" & " " & i
    Next i
End Sub
```

You can insert multiple columns at once by setting the a range to the number of columns you want to insert.

As an additional tip: always use explicit referencing of columns etc. --> `ws.Columns` vs. `Columns`.